# CodeIgniter conditional statement inside query

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

This is a simplified version of the code I have:

```
    $this->db->select('column1, column2, status, etc');

    if ($search['option_1']){
        $this->db->or_where('status', 15);
        $this->db->or_where('status', 20);
    }

    if ($search['option_2']){
        $this->db->or_where('status', 30);
        $this->db->or_where('status', 40);
        $this->db->or_where('status', 50);
    }

    if ($search['option_3']){
        $this->db->or_where('status', 99);
    }

    $this->db->where('column', $search['value']);
    etc..
```

On the webpage (a search form) I have, among other fields and select boxes, three checkboxes: option_1 to option_3. All checkboxes are optional. Each checkbox correspond to a status.

The checkboxes can be all checked, some checked or no checkbox checked.

I think the problem with this code is that brackets are missing around the OR statements and therefore "breaks" the query. Do I have to make:

```
    if ($search['option_1']){
            $this->db->where('(status = 15 OR status = 20)');
    }
    if ($search['option_1'] && $search['option_2']){
            $this->db->where('(status = 15 OR status = 20 OR status = 30 OR status = 40 OR status = 50)');
    }
    etc...
```

or is there a smarter way?

[UPDATE]
I'm using this until someone comes up with a better way:

```
   if($search['option_1'] || $search['option_2'] || $search['option_3']) {
        if ($search['option_1']){
            $status = '(status = 15 OR status = 20)';
        }
        else if ($search['option_2']){
            $status = '(status = 30 OR status = 40 OR status = 50)';
        }
        else if($search['option_3']) {
            $status = 'hr_olas.k_VALU_Status = 99';
        }
         else if($search['option_1'] && $search['option_2']) {
            $status = '(status = 15 OR status = 20 OR status = 30 OR status = 40 OR status = 50)';
        }
         else if($search['option_1'] && $search['option_3']) {
            $status = '(status = 15 OR status = 20 OR status = 99)';
        }
         else if($search['option_2'] && $search['option_3']) {
            $status = '(status = 30 OR status = 40 OR status = 50 OR status = 99)';
        }
         else if($search['option_1'] && $search['option_2'] && $search['option_3']) {
            $status = '(status = 15 OR status = 20 OR status = 30 OR status = 40 OR status = 50 OR status = 99)';
        }

        $this->db->where($status);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the good approach is  (status IN(15,20)),

but to debug your problem please print out the Query  to see whats wring

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: Well, technically there is nothing wrong with the query. The problem is that the OR statements combined with the standard AND is wrong from what I expect. This is due to the brackets missing around the OR statements.

Answer (score 0):

It suppose to be as follows:

```
       if ($search['option_1']){
            $this->db->select('column1, column2, status, etc');
            $this->db->or_where('status', 15);
            $this->db->or_where('status', 20);
            $this->db->where('column', $search['value']);
            etc
            $query = $this->db->get();
        }

        if ($search['option_2']){
            $this->db->select('column1, column2, status, etc');
            $this->db->where('column', $search['value']);
            $this->db->or_where('status', 30);
            $this->db->or_where('status', 40);
            $this->db->or_where('status', 50);

            etc
            $query = $this->db->get();
        }

        if ($search['option_3']){
            $this->db->select('column1, column2, status, etc');
            $this->db->where('column', $search['value']);
            $this->db->or_where('status', 99);
            etc
            $query = $this->db->get();
      }
```

Comment: I reread my question and I now see that it is not clear that the checkboxes can be all checked, some checked or no checked. I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('column1, column2, status, etc');
    $this->db->where('column', $search['value']);

        if ($search['option_1']){
             $this->db->or_where(array('status'=>'15','status'=>20));
        }

        if ($search['option_2']){
             $this->db->or_where(array('status'=>'30','status'=>'40','status'=>'50'));
        }

        if ($search['option_3']){
             $this->db->or_where(array('status'=>'99'));
        }

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Hope, It will helpful...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. Between the where and the or_where comes a OR in the query which is unwanted in this scenario.